# Is it possible to create nested elements in javascript using documentFragment?

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects, createelement, documentfragment

I would like to create a reuseable html block using documentFragment. The idea is to create and fill a block of html code similar to below, for every object in an existing array. I'm not worried about filling the inner html yet, for now I just want to build a nested hierarchy.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="titleABC">
        <h2 class="abc"></h2>
        <h2 class="efg"></h2>
        <h2 class="xyz"></h2>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I've add the code I was working on to a [js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LouKaz/w0s5tajn/12/).

I could not get more than one element to work in the document Fragment and was wondering if this is possible. Or if there is a better way to accomplish this, a steer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Ultimately I want to be able to add code like...
line 16, 17, 18, 19 in my js fiddle, and have a code block generated simply from having added it to the array.

Thank you in advance for time you waste helping me with my nonsense.

Comment: yes, a documentFragment can contain any HTML - your fiddle adds 4 elements to the fragment, and they get added to the body - what's the issue

Comment: also: you could `newDiv.classList.add(blaster.classID)` in the forEach, so you won't need the second loop - but still, what you're claiming happens, does not

Comment: you could also add `blaster.el = newDiv;` then you wouldn't need all those `let x =document.querySelector('.x');` ... since the `blastersAry` would hold each blaster, and each blaster would have a reference to the element created for it

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted without documentFragment in [this js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LouKaz/m6t0ny1r/21/).  
But I was unable to create a nested structure using documentFragment. My question is how is this possible with documentFragment as I get errors when i try to create nested html elements.